# how to move xmlns to envelope WCF

Tags: wcf, soap

I have a WCF Web Service, this must accept a request from a other non .net client, my problem is that WCF is especting the soap like this:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <myMethod xmlns="http://webservices.myServices/">
      <param1>ABC</param1>
      <param2>123</param2>
    </myMethod>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but the client is sending

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
xmlns:q0="http://webservices.myServices/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <q0:myMethod>
      <param1>ABC</param1>
      <param2>123</param2>
    </q0:myMethod>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The only difference is that xmlnamespace is inside the Envelope tag, but for some reason WCF dont understand it.

Comment: Apparently is a prefix problem, when I remove the q0 prefix of (<q0:myMethod>) it works fine, so Why WCF is not recognizing it?

Comment: The two examples are identical as far as WCF and XML are concerned.

Comment: yeap, but for some reason when I use the second one, (how non .net client sent) the WCF fire the method but all params arrive empty

Comment: Hold on, they're not identical. They would be identical if you had `q0:param1` and `q0:param2`.